# How to read .ini files in UWP C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, ini

I just started developing an application under the Microsoft `UWP` platform in `C#`.

I need to read an `.ini` file that contains a directory that loads the launch of the app, for now I have not found a solution.

Is it possible to read such a file with this platform? If so, do you have ideas of how I could do it?

Comment: Why use ini? its a very outdated file type

Comment: Why ini-files? Because of multi-platform I'd stick to [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/settings-learning-track).

Comment: Because the old application that I replace already uses this kind of file ... The best choice to replace them would be XML? @TheGeneral

Comment: @Valentin JSON is probably simplest these days.

Answer (score 0):

use DllImport

```
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string 
        def, StringBuilder retval, int size, string filePath);
```

for example :test.ini

```
[section]
name="john"
```

your code is

```
String GetIniContent(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
    var i = GetPrivateProfileString("section","name","",sb,1024,"file Path");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring) are the api in msdn